# "undefined method `database'" error using TinyTDS client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tiny-tds

Here is the code:

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa', password: 'secret', host: 'mydb.host.net, database: MYDB, dataserver: MYDS'
```

I want to test the connection and report if it is alive or not:

```
if client.active?
  puts "Connection to #{client.database} on #{client.dataserver} is alive"
else
  puts "Unable to establish connection to #{client.database} on #{client.dataserver}"
end
```

Here is the error:

```
<main>': undefined method `database' for #<TinyTds::Client:0x007f8b9384d840> (NoMethodError)
```

If client is an object, how do I access `database` and `dataserver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like you can. tiny_tds is pretty low-level, and has a very basic API. Consider using [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) as a higher-level database access layer that will give you a more convenient API to work with. Sequel can [use tiny_tds](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html#label-tinytds) to access appropriate databases.